# How to parse 'dd MMM yyyy'

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

How to convert date fromat from "dd MMM yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd"?

I know I have to use `SimpleDatFormat` but it doesn't work, neither does any solution from similar questions.

I have a date "18 Dec 2015" that I am trying to format but I get this

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18 Dec 2015"`

Here's my code:

```
public String parseDate(String d) {
    String result = null;
    Date dateObject = null;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    try {
        dateObject = dateFormatter.parse(d);
        dateFormatter.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        result = dateFormatter.format(dateObject);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: What's your default Locale? Try with `SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my date string does not have dashes

Comment: @ZouZou my locale is Poland

Comment: Read your exception carefully.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok i fixed a typo. I am for sure giving "18 Dec 2015" as input and i get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18 Dec 2015"` exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

(note the hyphens, since your pattern doesn't match your input)

Also helpful: using `Locale.US` as recommended by @ZouZou

Comment: Locale.US seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You are passing input as "18-Dec-2015" instead of the form "dd MMM yyyy". Try and pass input like 18 Dec 2015 and it should work.